# No exception is coming while sending message when kafka is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have scenario where kafka is getting down randomly. When i send message to kafka and it is down i want to handle it separately. But When i send message to kafka while it is down, no exception is coming and so i am not able to identify whether kafka is down or not. Is there any way i can catch exception and the lost message.

I have a very basic code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String topicName = "test-1";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
    }
    System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    producer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to send a synchronous call in order to get a response back from Kafka.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = 
              new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i));
    try {
           producer.send(record).get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           // Handle message that has failed
    }
}
```

Method `.get()` will return the response from Kafka. It will throw an exception when the record has failed to be pushed to Kafka. When the record has been successfully sent, then a `RecordMetadata` will be returned.